# internet explorer com object: prevent popup from showing but get url

Tags: javascript, com, internet-explorer-8

I want to achieve the following:

javascript code is executed which opens a popup (which would have to be done by calling window.open, as far as I can tell). However, I want to prevent the popup from showing while still getting the url that was supposed to be opened.

I am trying to only use the Internet Explorer's COM-events for this. I can receive the newWindow event and get the url, however I dont know how to prevent the popup from showing.

Does anyone happen to know how to do this?

So let's say the following JS-code was called:

```
<button id="test" onClick="window.open('http://localhost:1234/sev/index.html?test=popup');">go</button>
```

I want to get the url but prevent the popup from showing.

Comment: find the button by Id then get the Onclick attribute value and parse the string to get the url

Comment: well, the button is only an example. There will probably be no button.

Comment: Handle [`NewWindow3` event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768288.aspx). It comes with the URL for the new window, and with `Cancel` out parameter.

Comment: How do I use the cancel parameter? Doesnt that only tell me whether the user cancelled the navigation?